# Finding nearest percentage match to 2 strings, and returning next closest

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have some code which takes a user inputted value and a column from MySql table, I need it to run a percentage comparison and return the percentage, highest first, the second highest, third highest and so on.....

This is the code I am using so far:

```html
<?php

$result_while = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM store_table");

$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_while)) {
  $array[] = $row[name];
}

$words  = $array;

$string2= "Mr Peter Smith";

foreach ($words as $word) {

$percent = (1 - levenshtein($word, $string2)/max( strlen($word),strlen($string2) ) ) * 100;

$word . " - Percent match is: " . $percent[$word] . " </br>";
//60%

}


function compareStrings($s1, $s2) {
    //one is empty, so no result
    if (strlen($s1)==0 || strlen($s2)==0) {
        return 0;
    }

    //replace none alphanumeric charactors
    //i left - in case its used to combine words
    $s1clean = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/", ' ', $s1);
    $s2clean = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/", ' ', $s2);

    //remove double spaces
    while (strpos($s1clean, "  ")!==false) {
        $s1clean = str_replace("  ", " ", $s1clean);
    }
    while (strpos($s2clean, "  ")!==false) {
        $s2clean = str_replace("  ", " ", $s2clean);
    }

    //create arrays
    $ar1 = explode(" ",$s1clean);
    $ar2 = explode(" ",$s2clean);
    $l1 = count($ar1);
    $l2 = count($ar2);

    //flip the arrays if needed so ar1 is always largest.
    if ($l2>$l1) {
        $t = $ar2;
        $ar2 = $ar1;
        $ar1 = $t;
    }

    //flip array 2, to make the words the keys
    $ar2 = array_flip($ar2);


    $maxwords = max($l1, $l2);
    $matches = 0;

    //find matching words
    foreach($ar1 as $word) {
        if (array_key_exists($word, $ar2))
            $matches++;
    }

    return ($matches / $maxwords) * 100;    
}
?>
```

This works fine and gives me a long list of all the names and their percentage value next to them.  What I need is the highest first, and then in order.....

I need to output the range to a select dropdown box if that makes sense..... but also have the ability to pick the highest out to display in a separate row on my page.....

Thanks in advance.

Damian

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making this line:

```
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $percent = (1 - levenshtein($word, $string2)/max(strlen($word),strlen($string2) ) ) * 100;
    $word . " - Percent match is: " . $percent[$word] . " </br>";
//60%
}
```

This:

```
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $percent[$word] = (1 - levenshtein($word, $string2)/max( strlen($word),strlen($string2) ) ) * 100;
}
```

Then to sort the array from largest to smallest:

```
$percent = arsort($percent);
```

Then echo this:

```
foreach ($percent as $key => $value) {
   echo $key . " - Percent match is: " . $value . " </br>";
}
```

Comment: "$percent[$word] = (1 - levenshtein($word, $string2)/max( strlen($word),strlen($string2) ) ) * 100;" Want happens if the words has the same percent? right the array key will be overwritten.

Comment: Not sure why the array key would be overwritten if the values are the same.  If the key is the same then yes the value would be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks Jeff Mattson - this worked perfectly and did indeed sort as required - thanks for the help.....